# ref qualifier gives error in gcc4.7.2 and vc10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, g++

consider the below minimal example.

```
#include<iostream>

struct A
{
    A(){std::cout<<"def"<<'\n';}
    void foo()&{std::cout<<"called on lvalue"<<'\n';}
};

int main()
{   
    A a;
    a.foo();
    A().foo();
    return 0;
}
```

this gives error about `expecting ';' at the end of declaration` and `and expected un-qualified-id before '{'`.

Can i know what i'm doing wrong? in the actual code i want to avoid calling the non-static member function through temporaries.

tried on gcc 4.7.2 and vc2010.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer will be short: VC10 and GCC 4.7.2 do not support ref-qualifiers.

However, notice that your `foo()` function has an *lvalue* ref qualifier, meaning that you cannot invoke it on temporaries.

If you want this expression to compile as well:

```
A().foo();
```

Then you should use `const&`, or provide an overload for `&&`, as in this [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e66315fece67569b34707bd7dd3de69e-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336).

To work with ref-qualifiers you can use Clang 3.2 or GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: oh my god! so quick to answer:-). which version of either supports this?

Comment: btw gcc 4.8.1 was just released and is the 1st compiler to support them (clang 3.3 is due next week and will support them)

Comment: @andy as for your edit, thats what i was intending. not to call non-static member functions through temporaries.

Comment: @Koushik: Oh, all right then :) I edited the answer again, just to provide a more meaningful live example

Comment: @AndyProwl Thank you. waiting to accept the answer.:-) by the way know how to which features are supported and not in gcc?

Comment: @Koushik: GCC 4.8.1 is feature-complete :)

Comment: @Guillaume: Actually, Clang supports ref-qualifiers since version 2.9 if remember correctly ;)

Comment: @AndyProwl will update my compiler. clang is more efficient than gcc is it? heard some rumors so?

Comment: @Koushik: I can't really tell, although my experience is that Clang tends to be correct in most situations - but then again, take this with a grain of salt. I'd suggest you trying both.

Comment: @Koushik clang has a nice support for the c++ language.  Its optimizer has still some way to go.  For production (C++) code, I'd recommend g++.

Comment: @Guillaume is it that you suggest g++ and not clang for production code based on optimizer or is there some other reason?

Comment: @Koushik gcc is definitely more mature.  C++ in particular is not what clang supports the best (it would be a totally different story if you were doing Objective C).  I've tried every release of clang so far and it's always been slower for my benchmarks.  But apparently, this is changing with the next release:
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=llvm_clang33_3way&num=1

Comment: @Guillaume thank you very much. i'm also accustomed to gcc but will download clang too. i might need it when i'm debugging some code and in general.:)